# Compositions of compact operators

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Brezis shows that a compact operator $T \colon E \to E$ ($E$ a normed vector space) satisfies $0 \in \sigma(T)$ by showing that if $0 \notin \sigma(T)$, then $T$ is bijective and hence $I = T \circ T^{-1}$ is compact, a contradiction to infinite dimensionality. How do I see that 'hence $T \circ T^{-1}$ is compact'?

EDIT: are there any related results when $T$ is only surjecive or injective?

Comment: Um... do you mean $T: E \to E$ ?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by $\sigma(T)$ ?

Comment: Sorry, $T \colon E \to E$, but $\sigma(T)$ is standard notation for the spectrum...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This follows from the more general result

> If $T,S:E\to E$ are bounded linear maps and $T$ is compact, then $TS$ is compact

Indeed, since $S$ is bounded it maps bounded sets in $E$ to bounded sets in $E$.  Since $T$ is compact, it maps bounded sets in $E$ to precompact sets in $E$.  Thus $TS$ maps bounded sets in $E$ to precompact sets in $E$, and therefore $TS$ is compact.

---

Now assuming $T$ is compact and $0\notin\sigma(T)$, it has a bounded inverse $T^{-1}$ and applying the above result with $S=T^{-1}$, we see that $I=TT^{-1}$ is compact.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. I came up with that proof but was a bit surprised it required the bounded inverse theorem (which is only stated as a corollary and not used again until this chapter)

Comment: Would it be possible to conclude that if $TS = \mathrm{id}$, then neither $T$ nor $S$ is compact? I can see how to use the result in your post to show that $T$ is not compact, but I can't see why $S$ is not compact.

Comment: @user321210 through similar reasoning: Suppose $T$ is bounded, and $S$ is comapct. Thus $S$ maps bounded sets to precompact sets, and $T$ maps precompact sets to precompact sets.  So in this case, $TS$ maps bounded sets to precompact sets, and hence is compact.

Comment: @Aweygan Don't we require E to be Banach to apply the Bounded Inverse Theorem? Or are we showing the inverse to be bounded in another way?